# mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parame 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php

[image: Код страницы]

Выдаёт такую ошибку:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\OpenServer\domains\test.ru\index.php on line 14

Comment: `falCe` мне нравится особо в этом коде. Включили бы показ всех ошибок, предупреждений и уведомлений, и проблемы  бы не было

Comment: http://joxi.ru/Drlad3Bhvzbpkm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Может ты не подключился к бд,ты написал if($connection == falce)[должно быть false]
2.проверь,есть ли такая таблица,ибо запрос может возвращать фолс,также сделай isset($connection), и isset($result)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема, скорей всего находится в области кавычек. Строка запроса обрамлена в двойные кавычки, из-за чего `articles_categories` может пытаться выполниться как консольная (shell) команда. Лучше всего обрамить запрос в одинарные кавычки. Плюс таки не хватает вывода ошибки по какой причине запрос не выполнился и в $result вернулся false